# JavaFx AnimationTimer - I never stop my timers (ISSUE?)

Tags: java, javafx

I have multiple games in my program. 
They all use an AnimationTimer. I start the timer when I open a game but I never stop them when the game finishes or is exited. Ive never got an error but I feel like I should.

Is there a problem with not stopping animation timers when I finish my game and if so what will happen?

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timers owned by the process, and they're destroyed after destroying the game process (it's like all opened files are closed when app closes). Of course, it'd be better for a style programming to destroy all resources after exit.

Comment: So its not necessary but its good to close timers just in case?

Comment: Yes, you're right.